# How To Permanently Remove Movies Directory

Tags: macos

The directory ~/Movies:

```
16:43 $ tree /Users/ibodding/Movies
/Users/ibodding/Movies
└── TV
    ├── Media.localized
    └── TV\ Library.tvlibrary
        ├── Library\ Preferences.tvdb
        └── Library.tvdb
```

My .bash_profile deletes this every time on load, but it pops back up just as quickly.

I don't use any Apple applications aside from Finder and System Preferences. How can I prevent MacOS from recreating this directory?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using? Also, why bother with the directory, it doesn‘t use a significant amount of space.

Comment: Are you watching videos on another Apple device that's signed into your AppleID? phone, iPad, AppleTV box, etc.

Comment: @nohillside - 11.3.1, being able to control the files within my own home directory seems like an obvious ask

Comment: @benwiggy - No, I run two Macbooks (one for work, and one for personal projects) - on both I only use Finder and System Preferences Apple applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I prevent MacOS from recreating this directory?

If you do not mind having a hidden *file*, not *folder*, named **Movies** in the **Home** *folder*, then the *compound command* below, In **Terminal**, will do the following:

- Delete the **Movies** *folder*, including anything in it.
- Create a *file* named: **Movies**
- Sets an **ACL** of `everyone deny delete` on it.
- Remove all permissions for everyone to it.
- Hides the **Movies** *file*.

```bash
rm -R Movies; touch Movies; chmod +a 'everyone deny delete' Movies; chmod 0000 Movies; chflags hidden Movies
```

This effectively stops anyone, including the *system*, from creating a *folder* name **Movies** in the **Home** *folder* until the **ACL** is removed from the *file* **Movies** and the *file* is deleted.

For example, after running the above *compound command*, opening the **TV** *application* will not automatically recreate the a *folder* name **Movies** in the **Home** *folder*.

---

**Notes:**

Assumes the `pwd` in **Terminal** is your **Home** *directory* when running the *compound command* in **Terminal**.

The *compound command* used above was tested in **Terminal** under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary**, from an **Admin** account, and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

To remove the **Movies** *file* from **Terminal** afterwards:

```
chmod -N Movies
rm Movies
override ---------  $USER/staff hidden for Movies?
```

Type <kbd>Y</kbd> when prompted and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. With this solution I will still see the hidden file in terminal (where I do not want anything hidden from me). But marking as answer as this looks to be the best solution available.